¿Porque AdMob (ids de prueba) se muestra en iOS y en Android no en una app hecha con Flutter?
Alguien le ha pasado que al agregar AdMob con los Ids de prueba solo muestra los anuncios de prueba en el emulador de iOS y en el de Android no??? ya no encuentro la solución....será por el tipo de emulador que tengo en la Macboo Pro M2 ???

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. La descripción de tu problema parece estar bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil reproducir tu problema, identificar el error y responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.
